# Solving a modular equation

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

For a given $k \geq 0$, following identity holds for all positive integers $a$. How can I find $n$?
$$a^{n+k} \equiv a \mod n$$
Examples:

If $k=0$, then solution of $n$ is the set of all primes.

If $k=2$, solutions of $n \le 1000$ are $1,2,3,15,35,255,455$.

If $k=3$, solutions of $n \le 1000$ are $1,2,6,10,30,70,130,238,510,754,910$.

If $k=4$, solutions of $n \le 1000$ are $1,2,3,5,21,105,273,285,627$.

Comment: Do you mean that for $k=0$?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my bad. Of course $k=0$.

Comment: Before attempting to answer this question, please be aware that it is a slight generalization of Project Euler Problem 536, posted three days ago.  Given the similarity and the close proximity in time, that may not be a coincidence.

Comment: By the way, there is an excellent discussion of the algorithms to solve these problems at https://projecteuler.net/thread=536 , though you may not have access to that discussion until you've solved the problem.

Comment: I solved it 3 days ago. I saw the discussion. This problem is the generalized version.